# Dynamically Load a React Component using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to load a React Component from a Javascript file when a click event is triggered.
So basically,

```
function checkScript()
{
    var tab_content = document.getElementById('tab-content');
    var a = '<div id="notifications" class="tab-pane fade">'+
                '<h2 class="notify">Notify</h2>'+
                '<div id="NotifyComponent">'+
                  'Waiting to load notify'+
                '</div>'+
              '</div>';
    tab_content.innerHTML = tab_content.innerHTML + a;
    loadScript('/components/notifications.js', null);
}
$('#ap').click(function(e)
{
   checkScript(); 
});
```

This is a piece of code from my index.js file which I am using to load the React File, but the file isn't getting rendered.

However, if I use the following code, the rendering works just fine.

```
function checkScript()
{
    var tab_content = document.getElementById('tab-content');
    var a = '<div id="notifications" class="tab-pane fade">'+
                '<h2 class="notify">Notify</h2>'+
                '<div id="NotifyComponent">'+
                  'Waiting to load notify'+
                '</div>'+
              '</div>';
    tab_content.innerHTML = tab_content.innerHTML + a;
    loadScript('/components/notifications.js', null);
}
checkScript();
```

**This script loads the react component just fine, the only difference is that it's called directly when the Javascript file is loaded, not when a event is triggered.**

So, what changes do I make to load the react component on click event.!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap it up in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ap').click(function() {
     checkScript(); 
   });
});
```

Comment: yes, and as a matter of fact innerHTML gets inserted into tab_content. But the react component file isn't loading.!!

Comment: Well, need more info to help you. How does your file look like?

Comment: Do you support reactjs?

Comment: yes, the file gets rendered when used without the event click

Comment: Yes, jQuery is being used at some places

Comment: Where is your `ap` element?

Comment: ap element is a button in the index.ejs file.